# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation: Crashes during boot

Tags: boot, usb

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, wanted to install 16.04.
I created the 16.04 bootable USB stick using dd,

```
sudo dd if='-' of='-' bs=512
```

Now, when I try to boot that USB stick, it usually crashes during boot. I cannot even get to the Install Ubuntu screen. It crashes. Sometimes If I move the mouse, click or press in keyboard the GUI flashes a few times, but then it gets dark again. Sometimes, there is a warning that something has gone wrong.

Note: My GPU is GTX 960 which I recently purchased. When I installed 15.10 in my PC, it was a GT 640. After purchasing the 960, I replaced the 640 with it and the 15.10 installation worked without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions went well for me:

### How to install Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on a new PC

1. Insert a USB key, larger than 2GB
2. Format the USB with FAT32: **Spotlight > Disk Utility > ms-FAT + GUID**
3. Write the ISO file to the USB key with `unetbootin`
4. Boot the target PC from the USB key in UEFI mode
5. Select **Install Ubuntu**, adding the following boot parameters (next to `quiet splash`):  `pci=noaer pci pcie_aspm=off`
6. During the installation choose **Erase disk and install Ubuntu 16.04** and choose to install updates during installation (requires internet access)
7. When installation completes, reboot and then add the additional boot parameters mentioned in step 5 to the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   find the line and enter the additional parameters between the double quotes, separated by spaces, alongside `quiet splash` (order does not matter). Finally, the line should look like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer pci pcie_aspm=off"
   ```

   Save and exit, then run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to write the changes to GRUB's startup script.

Comment: this sounds like it would be specific to your hardware. Are you using the same device as the person who asked the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `bs=1M`.

If that doesn't work, use Ubuntu's built in utility called "Startup Disk Creator"
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't get the default ubuntu iso run in any way. The unity/gnome one would always crash. However, Ubuntu Mate runs (although a little choppy).

Comment: @ponir - Sounds like a driver issue.